# TSQL link data and split into matched and unmatched tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables of data which contain data something like as follows:-

```
|  id   | name |   dob    |          | name |   dob    |
|-------|------|----------|          |------|----------|  
| 12345 | ABC  | 20010301 |          | ABC  | 20010301 |  - matching record
| 45678 | DEF  | 20010425 |          | XYZ  | 20010301 |  - unmatched record
```

Is it possible to write a query which compares the two tables and then creates a match and unmatched table, leaving the orignal tables structure/data alone?

```
  Match Table        Unmatched Table
|  id   | rank |     |  id   | rank |   
|-------|------|     |-------|------|
| 12345 |  1   |     | 45678 | NULL |
```

I was experimenting with MERGE but I have to insert/update one source table and I have hit my ceiling in terms of tsql - I will also be dealing with datasets in excess of 30,000,000 rows - any advice/suggestions?
The sql (fields don't match but principle is there) I had so far is as follows?

```
Create TABLE #Cohort ([ID] varchar(4),[match rank] int)
INSERT INTO #Cohort ([ID],[match rank]) VALUES('aaaa',NULL)
INSERT INTO #Cohort ([ID],[match rank]) VALUES('bbbb',NULL)
INSERT INTO #Cohort ([ID],[match rank]) VALUES('cccc',NULL)
INSERT INTO #Cohort ([ID],[match rank]) VALUES('dddd',NULL)

Create TABLE #link ([ID] varchar(4),[match rank] int)
INSERT INTO #link ([ID],[match rank]) VALUES(left(NEWID(),4),NULL)
INSERT INTO #link ([ID],[match rank]) VALUES(left(NEWID(),4),NULL)
INSERT INTO #link ([ID],[match rank]) VALUES('aaaa',NULL)
INSERT INTO #link ([ID],[match rank]) VALUES(left(NEWID(),4),NULL)

Create TABLE #Matches ([ID] varchar(4),[match rank] int)
Create TABLE #Unmatched ([ID] varchar(4),[match rank] int)

MERGE #Cohort tg
USING (SELECT distinct c.[ID], 1 as [match rank] 
        from #Cohort c
        INNER JOIN #link as h on c.[ID]=h.[ID]) sc
ON (tg.[ID] = sc.[ID] )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
     THEN INSERT([ID],[match rank]) VALUES(sc.[ID],sc.[match rank])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
     THEN DELETE
OUTPUT Deleted.* INTO #Unmatched;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTE, at the end you will have on `#Matched` the matched rows and on `#Unmatched` the unmatched rows. As it currently stands, your `MERGE` statement deletes rows from #cohort table leaving just the one with the `aaaa` value.

```
CREATE TABLE #Cohort ([ID] VARCHAR(4),[MATCH RANK] INT)
INSERT INTO #Cohort ([ID],[MATCH RANK]) VALUES('aaaa',NULL)
INSERT INTO #Cohort ([ID],[MATCH RANK]) VALUES('bbbb',NULL)
INSERT INTO #Cohort ([ID],[MATCH RANK]) VALUES('cccc',NULL)
INSERT INTO #Cohort ([ID],[MATCH RANK]) VALUES('dddd',NULL)

CREATE TABLE #link ([ID] VARCHAR(4),[MATCH RANK] INT)
INSERT INTO #link ([ID],[MATCH RANK]) VALUES(LEFT(NEWID(),4),NULL)
INSERT INTO #link ([ID],[MATCH RANK]) VALUES(LEFT(NEWID(),4),NULL)
INSERT INTO #link ([ID],[MATCH RANK]) VALUES('aaaa',NULL)
INSERT INTO #link ([ID],[MATCH RANK]) VALUES(LEFT(NEWID(),4),NULL)

CREATE TABLE #Matches ([ID] VARCHAR(4),[MATCH RANK] INT)
CREATE TABLE #Unmatched ([ID] VARCHAR(4),[MATCH RANK] INT)

;WITH MatchedTbl AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT c.[ID], c.[MATCH RANK] 
     FROM #Cohort c
     INNER JOIN #link h ON c.[ID] = h.[ID]
)
INSERT INTO #Matches
SELECT c.[ID], c.[MATCH RANK]
  FROM MatchedTbl c

;WITH NonMatchedTbl AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT l.[ID], l.[MATCH RANK] 
      FROM #link l 
     WHERE l.ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM #cohort)
)
INSERT INTO #Unmatched
SELECT [ID], [MATCH RANK]
  FROM NonMatchedTbl

SELECT * FROM #Cohort
SELECT * FROM #Link
SELECT * FROM #Matches
SELECT * FROM #Unmatched

DROP TABLE #Cohort
DROP TABLE #link
DROP TABLE #Matches
DROP TABLE #Unmatched
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to look for matched / unmatched records is to perform a left join and look for NULLs in the left-joined table.

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.name) AS rank
INTO #MatchedTable
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

And:

```
SELECT t1.id, NULL AS rank
INTO #UnmatchedTable
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you could attempt if you are dealing with MASSIVE data.  If you still want to use a merge statement you could attempt to do this in BATCHES instead of all at once.  Or you could assign batches and do direct inserts.  Either way I would suggest a possible staging area, create an index, and then do inserts.  Assign batches with ntile function.  Self extracting example below that will run in SQL Server 2008 or higher:

```
declare @Person Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

insert into @Person values ('Brett'),('Sean'),('Chad'),('Michael'),('Ray'),('Erik'),('Quyen'),('John'),('Tim');

declare @Orders table ( OrderID int identity, PersonID int, Desciption varchar(32), Amount int);

insert into @Orders values (1, 'Shirt', 20),(1, 'Shoes', 50),(2, 'Shirt', 22),(2, 'Shoes', 52),(3, 'Shirt', 20),(3, 'Shoes', 50),(3, 'Hat', 20),(4, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Pants', 30),
(6, 'Shirt', 20),(6, 'RunningShoes', 70),(7, 'Shirt', 22),(7, 'Shoes', 40),(7, 'Coat', 80)

declare @Storage table ( batch int, personid int, person varchar(8), orderid int, Desciption varchar(32), amount int);

insert into @Storage

Select 
    ntile(5) over(order by p.PersonID)  
-- ntile does the number n inside across entire dataset so if I had 500 items 100 would each be different batch
,   p.personID
,   p.person
,   o.OrderID
,   o.Desciption
,   o.Amount
from @Person p
    left join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID
-- left join assures that when orders do not exist I still get the person

declare @Cursor int = 5
-- I can set a cursor for inserts based on batching.

-- pretend tables for matching
declare @Matched table ( personid int, person varchar(8), orderid int, Desciption varchar(32), amount int);
declare @UnMatched table ( personid int, person varchar(8), orderid int, description varchar(32), amount int);


insert into @Matched
select
    personID
,   person
,   OrderID
,   Desciption
,   Amount
from @Storage
where batch = @Cursor
and orderID is not null


insert into @UnMatched
select 
    personID
,   person
,   OrderID
,   Desciption
,   Amount
from @Storage
where batch = @Cursor
and orderID is null

select * From @Matched
select * From @UnMatched
```

My example is very simple but you can alter the 'cursor' variable to see different results that will occur from staging.  I will not run the whole set at a time due to batching and I could put data in storage then write a procedure to do the inserts based on a cursor or integer that will change.  You could even add a column for a bit reference whether the data was processed or not.